# CT scan heterogeneous dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset

I'm dealing with heterogeneous dataset of CT scan (DICOM files) with different pixel spacing. I'm trying to define a procedure that resample the volumes to a standard size in order to train e CNN. Particularly, I'm facing with this problem:

**volume 1**
size before resampling (512, 512, 215)  spacing [0.3125    0.3125    0.6999817]
size after resampling (160, 160, 150)  spacing [1.        1.        1.0033071]

**volume 2**
size before resampling (512, 512, 249)  spacing [0.367188 0.367188 0.268   ]
size after resampling (188, 188, 67)  spacing [1.00000136 1.00000136 0.996     ]

and so on. So after the resampling, all the volumes have the same physical spacing (1mm x 1mm x 1mm) but different pixel size. Consequently, supposing I want to train a CNN for sagittal plane, then I'll have different 2D images size. Am I missing something? Probably I haven't understood the difference between "pixel spacing", "physical spacing" and "image size".

The procedure that I wrote is only about resample the volumes in order to get the same pixel spacing (e.g. 1mm x 1mm x 1mm). However, this leads to different volume size.

Comment: I was thinking about this formula: new_spacing = (shape * spacing) / desired_shape. So in the end I'll have all the volume with same size but different spacing. What is the best approach considering a Deep Learning training?

Comment: I solved the problem just by wrapping all the volumes to a reference volume. That is to say cropping the volume if it is bigger than the reference one, otherwise padding the volume is the right operation.